# How can I PXE-boot SystemRescueCD with pur TFTP (no HTTP or NFS)?

Tags: linux, boot, pxe

As a base I started with the configuration of [TFTP-PXE-Boot-Server](https://github.com/paulmaunders/TFTP-PXE-Boot-Server). But now I also want to boot SystemRescueCD (version 2017-06-11) with using PXE.

I downloaded the ISO image and then on the TFTP-Server mounted the ISO as `images/sysresccd`. Following directions found in the [manual for PXE@sysresccd](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/manual/PXE_network_booting/) I added to my menu this:

```
LABEL SysRescCd
    MENU LABEL SysRescCd
    KERNEL images/sysresccd/isolinux/rescue32
    APPEND initrd=images/sysresccd/isolinux/initram.igz dodhcp netboot=tftp://MY_SERVER_IP/images/sysresccd/sysrcd.dat
```

The menu item shows up in the menu and when I select it then at first everything looks fine. But during the book, when it tries to download the sysrcd.dat, the download is very slow and when it reaches 7%, then the download stalls and then restarts and it does so in endless loops. What is wrong?

I don't want to start yet another service (like NFS).

Answer (score 1):

You [are not the only one with that problem](https://forums.system-rescue-cd.org/viewtopic.php?t=5279).

As written in the forum post linked, there is a workaround by modifying the initram.igz, so that is supports larger files over TFTP. It is not quite obvious how to do that, although the [manual about own kernels](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/manual/Build_a_custom_SystemRescueCd_with_your_own_kernel/) and [this question on about how to change a cpio archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241022) can help to put things together. Here is what you need to do:

```sh
# Temp dir to store the extracted initram.igz
mkdir /tmp/initram
cd /tmp/initram
# otherwise you'll get errors extracting the archive
fakeroot
# extract the initram.igz:
cat /mnt/sysresccd/isolinux/initram.igz | xz -d | cpio -id
# add the workaround parameter to init
sed -i 's/\/bin\/busybox tftp/\/bin\/busybox tftp -b 10000/' init 
# create a new initram.igz
find . | cpio -H newc -o | xz --check=crc32 --x86 --lzma2 > /tmp/sysresccd-initram.igz
```

Then use the new initram.igz in the pxelinux.cfg/default config file and booting works.